# enumerate each sub directory in a directory in bash

Tags: bash

```
for subdir in $( find $dir -type d ); do

    echo "subdir is $subdir"                                                                                                                            
done
```

the proble is that if the sub directory name contains space, they get separated, how do I resolve this?

Comment: `find $dir -type d -print0|xargs echo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for subdir in $somedir/*/ do
    echo "subdir is $subdir"                              
done
```

If you continue to have problems with spaces then you've goofed up your quoting elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process substitution`:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r subdir; do
    echo "subdir is $subdir"                                                                                                                            
done < <(find "$dir" -type d -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for subdir in $( find $dir -type d ); do
    echo "subdir is $subdir"
done
IFS=$oldifs
```

example:

```
$ bash dirnm.sh a
subdir is a
subdir is a/dir 1 
subdir is a/dir 2
```